# How to get mail of current day in AppleScript

Tags: email, applescript

How can I get new mail for the current day in apple script. I can get all of the new mail, but I want to see if it is possible to get mail for the current day?

This is what I have

```
tell application "Mail"
   check for new mail
   delay 1
set newMail to (messages of inbox whose read status is false)
end tell
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
tell (current date) to set midnight to it - (its time)
tell application "Mail"
    check for new mail
    delay 1
    set newMail to (messages of inbox whose date received comes after midnight)
end tell
```

Comment: you did this by setting the `current date` to midnight. Is there a way to set the `current date` to the last time the script run?

Comment: This is possible but elaborate. Variables and properties in standard scripts are not persistent because most of the running engines recompile the scripts before running them, so you would have to define a property and save the script as application or load and save a script object as a preference file.